# mysql update query case

Tags: mysql

```
+---------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Host                | User         | Password                                  |
+---------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost           | root         | *5372A5B70C563P98F01F290FB1DCAA165EA32AFA |
| sam01               | root         |                                           |
| john01              | root         |                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Consider the above sample table entry.
I have been trying to make a script to update the Password field with a default value for entries whose Password field is null.
I want to create a mysql query to update Password field with a default password for the Host whose Password is null. But the User field is root for all the entries.
The host name can change fom server to server.

Comment: Is the value null? Isn't it just empty?

Comment: The value can be empty or null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET `password`='DEFAULTPASS' WHERE `password` IS NULL
```

you can use also alter table

```
ALTER TABLE  `table` CHANGE  `password`  `password` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  'default_password';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table set password ='DefaultPassword' where password is null
```

It will update the null password with default one